# Repeatition of last letter in decoration while type setting the text

Tags: tikz-pgf

Instead of appearing *Meṣa*, *Vṛṣabha*, etc., in the diagram, an extra last letter is again appearing like *Meṣaa*, *Vṛṣabhaa*, etc., in the pdf after compilation. Could anyone resolve?

Please find the code below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inradi}{4.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ouradi}{5.5}
\filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (0:\inradi) arc (0:90:\inradi) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (180:\inradi) arc  (180:270:\inradi)  -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (90:\inradi) arc (90:180:\inradi) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (270:\inradi) arc (270:360:\inradi) -- cycle;
%
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\it|Meṣa||}, text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (30:\inradi) arc (30:0:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Vṛṣabha||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (60:\inradi) arc (60:30:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Mithuna||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (90:\inradi) arc (90:60:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Karkāṭaka||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (120:\inradi) arc (120:90:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Siṃha||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (150:\inradi) arc (150:120:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Kanyā||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (180:\inradi) arc (180:150:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Tulā||},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (180:\inradi) arc (180:210:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Vṛścika||},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (210:\inradi) arc (210:240:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={Dhanu},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (240:\inradi) arc (240:270:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={Makara},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (270:\inradi) arc (270:300:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={Kumbha},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (300:\inradi) arc (300:330:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={Mīna},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (330:\inradi) arc (330:360:\inradi);
%
\draw [thick] (0,0) circle (\ouradi);
\draw (210:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (30:\ouradi);
\draw (240:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (60:\ouradi);
\draw (300:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (120:\ouradi);
\draw (330:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (150:\ouradi);
\draw (-\ouradi,0)node[left]{$180^\circ$} -- (\ouradi,0) node[right]{$0^\circ$};
\draw (0,-\ouradi)node[below]{$270^\circ$} -- (0,\ouradi) node[above]{$90^\circ$};
%
\node[black] at (2,2) {{\large \textit{oja}}};
\node[black] at (-2,-2) {{\large \textit{oja}}};
\node[black] at (-2,2) {{\large \textit{anoja}}};
\node[black] at (2,-2) {{\large \textit{anoja}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

and the output looks like[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Just wondering why you use | and || in the nodes text? Also, you should provide code which compiles when we copy it, because then my next question would be obsolete: which language package do you use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just write `text={|\it|Meṣa},` instead of `text={|\it|Meṣa||},`. The vertical bars are to indicate a style for text, the double bar at the end is not needed and create this issue.

Comment: The double bar would be usefull if you wanted to type something in italics then something else not in italics, for example: `text={|\it|Mesa|| something else},`. You can change these delimiters with the parameter `text format delimiters={⟨before⟩}{⟨after⟩} `. Please see the manual: https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#sec-50.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `text effects along path` in a case like this. Then you don't need the `|` characters and can use `characters={font=\itshape}` to italicise the text.

I've also created styles to make the code clearer and enable easier modification. A base style sets up the `text effects along path` configuration. Two other styles then utilise this to render the text in upright and italics.

`\it` should not be used in LaTeX documents, so I've changed this to `\itshape`.

I don't know what language/font setup you're using, so I had to use `lualatex` to compile this. If you're using a different engine, you may need to protect accented characters.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% ateb https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699772/ i gwestiwn https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699727/
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{%
  fancy text effects/.style n args=3{%
    decorate,
    decoration={text effects along path,raise=#1, text={#2},text align=center,text effects/.cd, text along path, characters={font=#3}},
  },
  fancy italic text/.style 2 args={fancy text effects={#1}{#2}{\itshape}},
  fancy text/.style 2 args={fancy text effects={#1}{#2}{\normalfont}},
  oja/.style={fill=green!20!white, draw=black,thick},
  anoja/.style={fill=yellow!20!white, draw=black,thick},
  segment text/.style={black,font=\large\itshape},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\inradi}{4.5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ouradi}{5.5}
  \filldraw[oja] (0,0) -- (0:\inradi) arc (0:90:\inradi) -- cycle;
  \filldraw[oja] (0,0) -- (180:\inradi) arc  (180:270:\inradi)  -- cycle;
  \filldraw[anoja] (0,0) -- (90:\inradi) arc (90:180:\inradi) -- cycle;
  \filldraw[anoja] (0,0) -- (270:\inradi) arc (270:360:\inradi) -- cycle;
  %
  \draw[fancy italic text={0.35cm}{Meṣa}] (30:\inradi) arc (30:0:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy italic text={0.35cm}{Vṛṣabha}] (60:\inradi) arc (60:30:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy italic text={0.35cm}{Mithuna}] (90:\inradi) arc (90:60:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy italic text={0.35cm}{Karkāṭaka}] (120:\inradi) arc (120:90:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy italic text={0.35cm}{Siṃha}] (150:\inradi) arc (150:120:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy italic text={0.35cm}{Kanyā}] (180:\inradi) arc (180:150:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy italic text={-0.65cm}{Tulā}] (180:\inradi) arc (180:210:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy italic text={-0.65cm}{Vṛścika}] (210:\inradi) arc (210:240:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy text={-0.65cm}{Dhanu}] (240:\inradi) arc (240:270:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy text={-0.65cm}{Makara}] (270:\inradi) arc (270:300:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy text={-0.65cm}{Kumbha}] (300:\inradi) arc (300:330:\inradi);
  \draw[fancy text={-0.65cm}{Mīna}] (330:\inradi) arc (330:360:\inradi);
  %
  \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (\ouradi);
  \draw (210:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (30:\ouradi);
  \draw (240:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (60:\ouradi);
  \draw (300:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (120:\ouradi);
  \draw (330:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (150:\ouradi);
  \draw (-\ouradi,0)node[left]{$180^\circ$} -- (\ouradi,0) node[right]{$0^\circ$};
  \draw (0,-\ouradi)node[below]{$270^\circ$} -- (0,\ouradi) node[above]{$90^\circ$};
  %
  \node[segment text] at (2,2) {oja};
  \node[segment text] at (-2,-2) {oja};
  \node[segment text] at (-2,2) {anoja};
  \node[segment text] at (2,-2) {anoja};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result with italicised text along paths sans undesired doubling]

Comment: You can just put a properly scoped `\itshape` before the paths that need it and it will apply to the decoration as it would to nodes.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I didn't know that, thanks. In general, I prefer to have it in a style somewhere. But I don't usually get blocks of similar styling like this. Is there some advantage to doing it more directly?

Comment: Speed. The manual states `text effects along path` (more calculations per character, every character is a node) is slower than `text along path` (less calculations, every character is just a box). A style is a somewhat cleaner approach, of course. (Depending on the fonts, this also might change lengths in units `ex` and `em`.) In your style, you could get away with `/utils/exec=\itshape` even and then only have to switch to the font once per path instead of once per character. But that's probably more confusing.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I think it would make this answer more confusing, but I'm going to pinch that for somewhere else .... I figured the answer would likely be speed. But `text along path` is really difficult to get working properly.

Answer (score 5):

You need to brace non ASCII characters. Also adding `{}` seems to help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% <<< missing
\usetikzlibrary {decorations,decorations.text}% <<< missing

\tikzset{
  mydecoration/.style 2 args={
    decoration={
      text along path,
      text align=center,
      raise=#1,
      text=#2,
    },
  decorate,
  },
}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inradi}{4.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ouradi}{5.5}
\filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (0:\inradi) arc (0:90:\inradi) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (180:\inradi) arc  (180:270:\inradi)  -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (90:\inradi) arc (90:180:\inradi) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (270:\inradi) arc (270:360:\inradi) -- cycle;
%
\draw[mydecoration={0.35cm}{|\itshape|Me{ṣ}a{}||}] (30:\inradi) arc (30:0:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={0.35cm}{|\itshape|V{ṛ}{ṣ}abha{}||}] (60:\inradi) arc (60:30:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={0.35cm}{|\itshape|Mithuna{}||}] (90:\inradi) arc (90:60:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={0.35cm}{|\itshape|Kark{ā}{ṭ}aka{}||}] (120:\inradi) arc (120:90:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={0.35cm}{|\itshape|Si{ṃ}ha{}||}] (150:\inradi) arc (150:120:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={0.35cm}{|\itshape|Kany{ā}{}||}] (180:\inradi) arc (180:150:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={-0.65cm}{|\itshape|Tul{ā}{}||}] (180:\inradi) arc (180:210:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={-0.65cm}{|\itshape|V{ṛ}{ś}cika{}||}] (210:\inradi) arc (210:240:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={-0.65cm}{Dhanu}] (240:\inradi) arc (240:270:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={-0.65cm}{Makara}] (270:\inradi) arc (270:300:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={-0.65cm}{Kumbha}] (300:\inradi) arc (300:330:\inradi);
\draw[mydecoration={-0.65cm}{M{ī}na}] (330:\inradi) arc (330:360:\inradi);
%
\draw [thick] (0,0) circle (\ouradi);
\draw (210:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (30:\ouradi);
\draw (240:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (60:\ouradi);
\draw (300:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (120:\ouradi);
\draw (330:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (150:\ouradi);
\draw (-\ouradi,0)node[left]{$180^\circ$} -- (\ouradi,0) node[right]{$0^\circ$};
\draw (0,-\ouradi)node[below]{$270^\circ$} -- (0,\ouradi) node[above]{$90^\circ$};
%
\node[black] at (2,2) {{\large \textit{oja}}};
\node[black] at (-2,-2) {{\large \textit{oja}}};
\node[black] at (-2,2) {{\large \textit{anoja}}};
\node[black] at (2,-2) {{\large \textit{anoja}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I defined a style to ease input.

[image]

Comment: The image you've shown exhibits the same problem as the OP's.

Comment: @cfr Seems fixed now

Comment: Thanks, though I prefer `text effects along path` in this kind of case. Then you can put the font stuff into a style and dispense with the `|` business completely. (But it may make compilation slower, I'm not sure.)

Comment: May I know how do we deal if we use macros in defining texts like \def\mesha{\textit{Meṣa}}, and wanted to use it in decoration text like: text={\mesha}

Comment: @YelluruNagakiranhs21d021 I don’t think you can, sorry. Bracing the non ASCII characters is essential anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble seems to come from the `|` and `||`, as I suspected. There are a number of problems from your code snippet, which prevents me to compile it.

#### About the solution

Please compare these two lines of code:

```
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={Mesa}, 
text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (30:\inradi) arc (30:0:\inradi);

\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Vrsabha||},
text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (60:\inradi) arc (60:30:\inradi);
```

The first line without the `|` doesen't double the last character, while with it does.

#### About your posted code

At least these lines are vital for a compile of your code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% <<< missing
\usetikzlibrary {decorations,decorations.text}% <<< missing
```

For some reason you had one `}` too many at the end:

```
\end{tikzpicture}%}   % <<< one brace too many
```

Because you didn't specify the language in your code, I had to replace your writings like below, just to compile:

```
Meṣa
Mesa
```

#### Unresolved

The text isn't italic at the moment. Please review in the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/)  the way this kind of font specification can be done in Tikz and/or it is expected to be on a decoration path.

You may also replace all those individual format specifications by self defined styles. This both improves readability, reduces errors, and allows a "change in one place only" approach.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% <<< missing
\usetikzlibrary {decorations,decorations.text}% <<< missing

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inradi}{4.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ouradi}{5.5}
\filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (0:\inradi) arc (0:90:\inradi) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (180:\inradi) arc  (180:270:\inradi)  -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (90:\inradi) arc (90:180:\inradi) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20!white, draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (270:\inradi) arc (270:360:\inradi) -- cycle;
%
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={Mesa}, text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (30:\inradi) arc (30:0:\inradi);
\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Vrsabha||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (60:\inradi) arc (60:30:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Mithuna||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (90:\inradi) arc (90:60:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Karkāṭaka||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (120:\inradi) arc (120:90:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Siṃha||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (150:\inradi) arc (150:120:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Kanyā||},text align = center,raise=0.35cm},decorate] (180:\inradi) arc (180:150:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Tulā||},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (180:\inradi) arc (180:210:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={|\it|Vṛścika||},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (210:\inradi) arc (210:240:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={Dhanu},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (240:\inradi) arc (240:270:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={Makara},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (270:\inradi) arc (270:300:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={Kumbha},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (300:\inradi) arc (300:330:\inradi);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,text={Mīna},text align = center,raise=-0.65cm},decorate] (330:\inradi) arc (330:360:\inradi);
%
\draw [thick] (0,0) circle (\ouradi);
\draw (210:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (30:\ouradi);
\draw (240:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (60:\ouradi);
\draw (300:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (120:\ouradi);
\draw (330:\ouradi)[dashed] -- (150:\ouradi);
\draw (-\ouradi,0)node[left]{$180^\circ$} -- (\ouradi,0) node[right]{$0^\circ$};
\draw (0,-\ouradi)node[below]{$270^\circ$} -- (0,\ouradi) node[above]{$90^\circ$};
%
\node[black] at (2,2) {{\large \textit{oja}}};
\node[black] at (-2,-2) {{\large \textit{oja}}};
\node[black] at (-2,2) {{\large \textit{anoja}}};
\node[black] at (2,-2) {{\large \textit{anoja}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%}   % <<< one brace too many
 
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response... You are right in analyzing about '|' but that is how it is given in the pgfmanual in the decorations section. I don't know why an extra letter at the end is repeating

Comment: See above: „ The first line without the | doesen't double the last character, while with it does.“

Comment: I want to typeset the text to italics for which in pgfmanual the syntax specifies to use delimiters '|'. Could you suggest any way to italicize it but not repeat the last letter?